# Unable to set CSV as payload in Mule

Tags: csv, mule, sftp, anypoint-studio

I am trying to create a flow in Mule 3.7.3 which reads a CSV file from an input folder, does some processing and then writes the original CSV file to an output folder at the end of the flow when everything has completed successfully.

I thought I would save the CSV in a variable and then set the payload using this variable before it creates the file in the output directory.

Everything worked ok when I just had the two sftp connectors to read and write in the flow but then when I added a transform message connector, the file written to the output folder is empty or it fails with a "stream closed" error message.  I would have expected the set payload connector to overwrite the transform message so wouldn't have thought there would be a problem.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

The SFTP server I am using is CrushFTP.

XML flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:mulexml="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml" xmlns:ftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:sftp="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp" xmlns:batch="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sftp/current/mule-sftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/batch/current/mule-batch.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/ftp/current/mule-ftp-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ftp/current/mule-ftp.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/xml/current/mule-xml.xsd">
    <http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" host="${host}" port="${orderprocess.port}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"></http:request-config>
    <sftp:connector name="SFTP" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SFTP" pollingFrequency="1000000"/>
    <flow name="userFlow">
        <sftp:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="SFTP" host="localhost" port="2222" path="//input" user="${ftp.user}" password="${ftp.password}" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP"/>
        <set-variable variableName="storeCsv" value="#[payload]" mimeType="application/csv" doc:name="Store CSV"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/csv"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <set-payload value="#[flowVars.storeCsv]" mimeType="application/csv" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <sftp:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" host="localhost" port="2222" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="SFTP" connector-ref="SFTP" password="${ftp.password}" path="//output" user="${ftp.user}" outputPattern="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename+'.processed']"/>
    </flow>  
</mule>
```

CSV file

```
1, user1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `<object-to-string-transformer/>` after `<sftp>` connector

Comment: Thanks.  I had just worked that out at the same time :)